# Is there way to un-nest a list column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with a list as one of the columns. I want to expand that list out into 4 separate columns.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,8]]})
df
Out[458]: 
   A  B
0  1  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1  2  [1, 2, 5, 8]
```

I'd like this to be:

```
   A  C_1  C_2  C_3 C_4
0  1  1    2    3   4
1  2  1    2    5   8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all lists have the same length, you can do:

```
df[['A']].join(pd.DataFrame(df['B'].values.tolist(),
                            index=df.index)
                 .add_prefix('C_')
              )
```

Output:

```
   A  C_0  C_1
0  1    1    2
1  2    1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Pandas string methods to pull the data, assuming the length is the same for each row in column `B` :

```
mapping ={f"C_{num+1}" : df.B.str[num] 
          for num in range(df.B.str.len()[0])
          }

df.drop(columns="B").assign(**mapping)

   A  C_1  C_2  C_3  C_4
0  1    1    2    3    4
1  2    1    2    5    8
```